# Cannot add dynamic child arraylist to header arraylist expandablelistview android?

Tags: android, arraylist, retrofit, expandablelistview

```
    private ArrayList<String> listDataHeader;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
private int i,j,k;
List<String> addChild=new ArrayList<String>();
private List<Guide> guideList=new ArrayList<>();
```

in onCreate i have done

```
expListView=(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);

prepareDataList();

listAdapter=new MyExpandableListAdapter(this,listDataHeader,listDataChild);

    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

Here is the prepareDataList() method -
here is the prepared list data where i have fetching category and child item data

```
   private void prepareDataList() {
   listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
   listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Here is the Retrofit to get the Category data from response

```
Retrofit retrofit = apiClient.getClient();
 apiRest service = retrofit.create(apiRest.class);
Call<List<Category>> call = service.categorriesList();
  call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Category>>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<Category>> call, @NonNull 
final Response<List<Category>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                for (i=0;i<response.body().size();i++){
```

Here i am adding response category title data to listDataHeader
further i have created next retrofit response to get item list from category id by response.body().get(i).getId.toString();

```
                    listDataHeader.add(response.body().get(i).getTitle());

     Retrofit retrofit1 = apiClient.getClient();
     apiRest service1 = retrofit1.create(apiRest.class);
                    Call<List<Guide>> call1 = 
service1.guidesByCategory(response.body().get(i).getId().toString());
                    call1.enqueue(new Callback<List<Guide>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<Guide>> 
call1, @NonNull Response<List<Guide>> response1) {
                            if (response1.isSuccessful()){
                                if (response1.body().size()!=0){
                                    for (j=0;j<response1.body().size();j++){


guideList.add(response1.body().get(j));

addChild.add(guideList.get(j).getTitle());

                                    }



                                }

                            }
                        }
               @Override
               public void onFailure(Call<List<Guide>> call1, Throwable t) {
                        }
                    });



     listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get
     (listDataHeader.size()-1),addChild);
                    addChild.clear();
                    listDataHeader.clear();

  Log.e("PARENT_AND_CHILD","PARENT IS ="+(listDataHeader.size()-1)+" AND 
  CHILD IS ="+addChild);
                }


             }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Category>> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });

}
```

here is the adapter i have created

```
 package com.stackheaps.how_to.adapter;


 public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

public MyExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                             HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}


@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(i))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int i) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(i);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(i)).get(i1);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
    return i1;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    String headerTitle=(String)getGroup(i);
    if(view==null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)_context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group,null);
    }

    TextView txtHeader=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
    txtHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    txtHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return view;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final String childText=(String)getChild(i,i1);

    if(view==null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);
    }

    TextView txtChild=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.expandedListItem);
    txtChild.setText(childText);
    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
    return false;
  }
```

}

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
listDataHeader.clear();
```

Everytime you clear the data in listDataHeader so it holds only one data at index 0. First time your for loop i = 0 so it executes correctly.

**Alternate**

change this line

```
listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i),addChild);
```

To

```
listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0),addChild); //0 as index
```

so everytime it takes data from index 0.

Comment: did you tried remove this line listDataHeader.clear(); -- update your response data.

Comment: yes. I am Getting Category's now but now items list r empty.as previous same output

Comment: E/CATEGORY LIST: CAREGORY ARE [C Programming] AND ID IS 12
E/GUIDE LIST For Category: [C Programming] Have GUIDE ARE []
E/CATEGORY LIST: CAREGORY ARE [C Programming, C++] AND ID IS 13
E/GUIDE LIST For Category: [C Programming, C++] Have GUIDE ARE [] i have checked in logcat guide gives no item by category id

Comment: You mean you cannot get items based on category ID.

Comment: i have used same guidesByCategory method in another activity there the output comes but while retrieving here its not coming.

Comment: response.body().get(i).getId() from this code you didnot get ID. so ""Have GUIDE ARE [] "" these are empty list.

Comment: guidesbycategory(string)..string which is Category ID or Category Name.

Comment: Now i am getting items in arraylist by [private List<Guide> guideList=new ArrayList<>();][guideList.add(response1.body().get(j));
 addChild.add(guideList.get(j).getTitle());] but now when i add [ addChild ] to  [listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0),addChild);] nothing is displayed

Comment: How do i put addChild items to list? I have tried this [listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i),addChild);] but gets actvity error  as [Invalid index 2, size is 2]

Comment: guideList.add(response1.body().get(j)); change to get title guideList.add(response1.body().get(j).getTitle();  & addChild.add(guideList.get(j));

Comment: I have done this [ guideList.add(response1.body().get(j));]
       [addChild.add(guideList.get(j).getTitle());] it give me child item but when i add addChild to [listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i),addChild);] it shows error [Invalid index 2, size is 2]

Comment: sry.....but still it showing [Invalid index 2, size is 2].i want listDataHeader.get(here i want index of listDataHeader of  every category),addChild)

Comment: now listDataHeader contain all category and addChild contains all item now how do i differentiate them based on category or i mean how do i categorize items based on category

Comment: You already categorize your category in listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i),addChild); You can get List<String> = listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(i)). It will give child list based on category.

Comment: see your response1 data based on each category. In addchild list you add the childs for particular category right? didn't find prepareDataList()..?

Comment: This whole thing getting category and child item I have put in method prepareDataList() which is called in onCreate after than I have set adapter .so I want the prepareDataList to prepare data for category and child item

Comment: did you pass listDataChild in adapter class.

Comment: see i Have updated code of the activity please tell me where i am wrong.

Comment: OK wat s the issue now there is no data in category r no data in child r completely your expandable listview empty.?

Comment: You are not passing your list to your adapter i would you suggest you to look at this tutorial create seperate class for adapter and pass your list to adapter. http://abhiandroid.com/ui/expandablelistadapter-example-android.html

Comment: Otherwise try to call listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after set adapter to listview.

Comment: i have created adapter but still there is problem passing listDataHeader and listDataChild  from prepareDataList() .there is something wrong in prepareDataList().bcoz activity opens but cannot see anything . expandablelistview cannot be seen as not data is going.what's the problem?

Comment: You create seperate adater class? can you update question your adpater code.

Comment: call listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after set adapter line

Comment: listAdapter not having notifyDataSetChanged() method . it only have noitfy & notifyAll.

Comment: i think there is wrong in preparedDatList. but i dont know what is the mistake?is there anything wrong in for loop's to pass the value in listDataHeader & listDataChild

Comment: i will update you. check getGroupCount() & getChildCount() returns size or zero

Comment: see in preparedDataList() in have used Log.e TAG "PARENT_AND_CHILD here i am receiving PARENT=0 AND CHILD =[].Why?

Comment: don't use clear method it clears the data in the arraylist thats you getting zero and empty array.